# How to check what schema has been selected in Sequelize without using raw queries

Tags: typescript, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to find the schema that I have selected while creating sequelize connection?

I read the documentation but couldn't find any information.

I know we can specify schema while creating 'new Sequelize' connection.

I logged the instance created 'new Sequelize' but that doesn't contain selected schema details.

If any guidance is provided, would be appreciated?

Trying to find the selected schema.